# how to convert .PHP code to .JSP file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jsp, servlets

im new in web programming and i have some problems, so it will be great if you can give me some suggestions...

Ok, i have 3 separate files index.html, foodstore.js and foodstore.php
When i run index.html on the localhost then i can use some ajax advantages.
But how to combine those 3 files in one file .jsp ?

In foodstore.js i have function called process(); and it runs `<input type="text" id="userInput" onkeyup="process()" />`

I can put all code under the  section but what to do with this function that referencing me to foodstore.php ?

```
function process() {


    food = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("userInput").value);
    //alert(food);
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "foodstore.php?food="+food, true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
    xmlHttp.send();
```

}

Dont know if its possible to convert PHP page to JSP page. Here is a that referenced file foodstore.php and i want to know if is possible to code this into the .jsp and what to change in function process(): `xmlHttp.open("GET", "foodstore.php?food="+food, true);`

Here is the code from foodstore.php :

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';

echo '<response>';
    $food=$_GET['food'];
    $foodArray = array('Aik banka','Hypo bank','Reiffeisen','Societe Generale','Komercijalna banka', 'Banca intesa', 'Alpha bank');

    if (in_array($food,$foodArray)) {
    echo "".$food." posluje sa nama" ;
    } elseif ($food==''){
        echo "Morate uneti tacan naziv banke. (pocetak reci je sa velikim slovom. Npr. Aik banka, Hypo bank...)";
    } else {
        echo    "Izvinjavamo se, ali ".$food.' ne saradjuje sa nama';
    }

echo '</response>';
```

?>

Comment: You're basically looking to convert it into Java, not JavaScript, which is a completely different language.

Comment: There are some sites where you can hire freelancer for this type of tasks (even me). Unfortunately here, on SO, users don't work for others. . .

Comment: What's with that random tagging? Do you want it ported to Java, javascript, both? What's the deal with AJAX? Anyhow, nobody will do that for you here, I'm sorry, please have a look at the [help](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) section to know what kind of questions are allowed on SO

Comment: You can convert that code from php to jsp, the answer is yes...now how, just find the apropiate code to correspond with each other...example: PHP $food=$_GET['food']; Java <%= request.getParameter("food")%>

Comment: thanks guys, sorry for boring you im new in web programming

Comment: SO is about helping solving problems. your problem is you don't want to do it yourself. that isn't SO related

Comment: @gwillie beleve me i will do that if i know, but i dont know how. it will be helpfull if you can tell me where i can learn that to convert php code to jsp. thanks

Comment: @PredragStevanović Why do you want to convert the code to JSP if you don't understand Java?

Comment: @Bart i need that because i might get job+education in one company in Belgrade