# PHP and JavaScript into JSP

Tags: javascript, php, jsp

I am new in web programming and I have some problems, so it will be great if you can give me some suggestions.

Ok, I have 3 separate files `index.html`, `foodstore.js` and `foodstore.php`.
When I run index.html on the localhost then I can use some ajax advantages.
But how to combine those 3 files in one file .jsp?

In foodstore.js I have function called process(); and it runs `<input type="text" id="userInput" onkeyup="process()" />`

I can put all code under the  section but what to do with this function that referencing to my foodstore.php?

```
function process() {


    food = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("userInput").value);
    //alert(food);
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "foodstore.php?food="+food, true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
    xmlHttp.send();
```

}

Don't know if it's possible to convert `PHP` page to `JSP` page. Here is a that referenced file foodstore.php and I want to know if it is possible to code this into the .jsp and what to change in function process(): `xmlHttp.open("GET", "foodstore.php?food="+food, true);`

**foodstore.php:**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';

echo '<response>';
    $food=$_GET['food'];
    $foodArray = array('Aik banka','Hypo bank','Reiffeisen','Societe Generale','Komercijalna banka', 'Banca intesa', 'Alpha bank');

    if (in_array($food,$foodArray)) {
    echo "".$food." posluje sa nama" ;
    } elseif ($food==''){
        echo "Morate uneti tacan naziv banke. (pocetak reci je sa velikim slovom. Npr. Aik banka, Hypo bank...)";
    } else {
        echo    "Izvinjavamo se, ali ".$food.' ne saradjuje sa nama';
    }

echo '</response>';
?>
```

Comment: php and jsp are two distinct technologies, running on different server stacks.  Converting between those has to be done manually (ie translate), but in this case I'd put the processing logic you show in a servlet and ***not*** in a JSP.  jsp is a view technology and ideally you should have no processing logic whatsoever inside your JSP, for maintainability.

Comment: You know that JSP is Java Server Pages right? And that you'll probably want to be running a completely different server environment for that, Apache Tomcat perhaps.

Comment: im using already apache tomcat for jsp pages

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert .PHP code to .JSP file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19930307/how-to-convert-php-code-to-jsp-file)

Comment: @DamienPirsy yes it is, please some suggestions

Comment: I suggest to edit the original question instead of creating another one

Comment: Javascript stays the same no matter what serverside language you use, so all you need to change in your javascript is .php to .jsp when its calling Ajax.  As for the rest, if you know Java and PHP both, you know how to convert between them.  If you don't, you need to learn them.